# D3 runs in edge and firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I am currently working on a tree that is designed using d3.js. Right now, the .html runs prefectly in Edge and firefox, but will not load the graphic in chrome. Additionally, when I change dataLoadUrl from a local file to a github stored file it runs fine on chrome.

Here is the snippet of code I suspect to be the issue

```
dataLoadUrl: "data.json",
d3.json(params.dataLoadUrl, function(data) {                                              
  params.data = data;                                                               
  params.pristinaData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));                
  drawOrganizationChart(params);})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: are you running server on local ? directly opening .html file won't allow a local file to be accessed in chrome

Comment: Can you share the content of your HTML file?

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. There are numerous posts around dealing with various aspects of this issue. Bottom line: you cannot load local files like this; at least not without deactivating security featues. Try searching for your error message or "[d3] load local file" or something like that to get more help.